# Angularjs: changing the format of strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several strings that I need to change the format of with angularjs:

**String 1**

Change strings to 10 digits without the letter in front

1. A 908915-10  ==  0090891510
2. B 6918546-05 == 0690891510
3. C 90002135-00 == 9000213500

**String 2**

Change decimal to 10 digits

1234.00 == 0000123400

**String 3**
530706-01 == 53070601

How do I go about changing each of the above?

Comment: @TonyBarnes I don't even know where to start really. The tax office just handed me some specs and I haven't had much experience manipulating strings in javascript beyond concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String 1 & 3 :**

Remove all non-digit characters :

```
your_string.replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

**String 2 :**

You have to write a function that remove all non-digit char (use the same function for the string 1 & 3). then add in front position as much "0" as possible to have a length of 10